# How can I make this striped background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, graphic-styles

How can I replicate this pattern?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open a new blank image in Photoshop, add a new layer, and create a rectangular selection 25 pixels high. Fill it black. Copy and paste it and space it 25 pixels down, and repeat for a third stripe. Make sure Smart Guides are enabled, as it will make the task much easier.

[image: Pasting and spacing stripes]

Select all three stripe layers, and group them. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to transform, and rotate -45°, and apply the Transform. Note: Mac users use <kbd>Command</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

[image: Rotating grouped layers with Transform]

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> again, and you will see the centre target appear. Zoom into this until you can see the pixel grid. Click and drag a horizontal and vertical guide from the ruler, to intersect with the centre target.

[image: Adding guides]

Choose the Rectangular Marquee tool. Hover your mouse over the intersecting guides which mark the centre, and hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag to constrain the selection to an exact square, and expand from the centre, making the selection corners go as far as exactly half way through the adjoining diagonal stripe.  It is tricky getting it exactly half way - but if you don't get it right, the pattern will not be tileable.

Click `Edit` > `Define Pattern`. Give the pattern a new name.

[image: Making selection into a Pattern]

To use your new pattern, open a new blank document. Select the Bucket Fill tool, in the tool options select "Pattern" from the dropdown, and click the pattern dropdown box, and select your pattern. Click on your image to apply the pattern.

[image: Applying the pattern]

If you don't want to make your own custom pattern, go visit deviantart(dot)com, and do a search for Photoshop stripe patterns. There are many which are free to download. To use them, simply download and double click the PAT file to load them into your patterns in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

First, Make a new Document

Second, Click the Gradient Tool

Third, Click the "Click to edit the gradient" at the upper left part of the window

Fourth, Select the "Transparent Stripes" swatch

Fifth, Click OK

Sixth, Drag the mouse pointer from the upper left part to the lower right part of the canvas / document.

Voila! Done.

PS. If you want to add more stripes, stop at fourth step then add new markers and set their colors below the bar.